# How can I Iterate over nested object in React(rendering any data in the screen and set the state in a immutable way)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, nested-object

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState({
  "users-1": {
    id: "01",
    email: "user1@dame.com",
    name: "alexa",
    userName: "alexa01",
    role: "",
    mobileNumber: "+1363545454",
    password: "fdtgs",
    registrationDate: "",
    address: {
      division: "Dhaka",
      city: "Savar",
      road: 20,
    },
    institute: "",
  },
  "users-2": {
    id: "02",
    email: "user-02@dame.com",
    name: "OkayGoogle",
    userName: "OkayGoogle02",
    role: "",
    mobileNumber: "+4564545454",
    password: "",
    registrationDate: "",
    address: {
      division: "Rangpur",
      city: "Nilphamari",
      road: 21,
    },
    institute: "",
  },
});
```

question:
no1- how can I iterate this object like an array and displayed some information on the screen
no:2 -- how can I manipulate copied data and set the state
no-2 -- what is the most efficient way of doing this?

NB: I used this as well `"Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])"`
it doesnot create a new object.
TIA

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, but could it be simplified too >>. Given an object is there a way to automatically edit this in react?  If so, this might be a good starting point. https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-editor-react

Comment: "how can I iterate this object like an array" why ain't this object an array? It seems to represent a list of users. It would make sense to use a list (array) to represent a list.

Comment: This is how i think your array should look like [{"users-1":{}},{"users-2":{}}], yours look like an object rather than an array.

Comment: Array does linear search and Object does binary search under the hood..  that's why My project manager create this kind of data structure @Thomas

Comment: this is the normal data structure every API use but mine was different.. thats why i asked the question @ Manti_Core

Comment: I will keep it in my mind.. thanks for the suggestion @ Keith

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sandbox that shows name and email of user in Person state and button that add new user to it. I think it will answer your no1 & no2.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-voice-9lmuc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i saw your answer. but Object.keys() does not make a new array rather mutate data in the main array.

Comment: I have used Object.keys() to iterate over data stored in Person state and show its data on screen. It was never meant to make a new array nor mutate data in main array. and by array are you referring to Person state Object?

Comment: yes indeed. my bad. that's understandable. but how can I get like adress.city in every user.

Comment: I made changes in codesandbox to render name and city.